# How can I resolve Undefined name 'currency' in Flutter for-in loop?

Tags: flutter, dart, for-in-loop, dart-analyzer, undefined-variable

## Background

While following London App Brewery's Bitcoin Ticker project, and I got stuck trying to create `DropdownMenuItem`s via a for-in loop. The warning that the Dart Analysis gave me was [`Undefined name 'currency'`](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#undefined_identifier). Here's the code that produced the error:

## Problematic Code

```dart
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> buildCurrencyDropdownMenuItems() {
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items = [];
  for (currency in currenciesList) {
    items.add(DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(currency), value: currency));
  }
  return items;
}
```

## Question

What does *Undefined name 'currency'* mean in Dart? Does that really mean it's an undefined *variable* named 'currency'?

Answer (score 0):

## Android Studio IDE Hint

My IDE gave me three hints, and the top one *Create local variable 'currency'* seemed to be the correct solution. However, it creates the variable outside of the for-in loop. **The problem was that `currency` in the for-in loop wasn't defined**.

### Create local variable 'currency'

[image: Create local variable 'currency']

### Local variable 'currency' defined outside for-in loop

Technically, this way of defining `currency` is correct, but is verbose and requires an extra line of code.
[image: Local variable 'currency' defined]

### Solution

I placed the variable type inside the for-in loop [like they show in the Dart docs](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#iteration). I also changed the generic `var` to the more specific `String` type for each item in the list.

```dart
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> buildCurrencyDropdownMenuItems() {
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> items = [];
  for (String currency in currenciesList) {
    items.add(DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(currency), value: currency));
  }
  return items;
}
```